# Animations in Bootstrap v4.1 are not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

The animations in version 4.1 of Bootstrap are not working in my notebook. I tried using in my own code and directly from the examples of the Bootstrap site itself, but both are failing to work. But in other versions such as version 4.alpha are working properly. What do I do?

I tried to run the code on my notebook, on a friend notebook and my teacher notebook, and in theirs, the animation works properly, in both versions, but in mine, don't. The primary animation that I'm trying to make work is the collapse animation in a navbar.

This my code:

```
<div class="pos-f-t">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
            <div class="navbar-nav cor-navbar pt-4 pl-4 pr-4 pb-1">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link text-dark" href="#">lorem</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link text-dark" href="#">lorem</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link text-dark" href="#">lorem</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link text-dark" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">lorem</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar cor-navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                    <div class="col">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="home.html">E-dificio</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <div class="row text-center border-bottom"><a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">Fulano de tal</a></div>
                        <div class="row text-center text-dark">Apartamento X</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-right">
                        <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

This are the repositories i'm using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And i'm using a custom css:

```
.cor-navbar {
      background-color: #f7ca16;

}

.cor-body {
      background-color: #ffeeab;
}

.custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
    border-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0,0,0)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

And for last, this is the official example i'm testing directly from Bootstrap in other computers:
https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.0/examples/album/

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: i'm coding in Brackets, so i'm using chrome, but im tried in Opera, Edge and Firefox and the same happens